# Removing extreme values from a Matrix in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, outliers

I have a matrix with x-y data points:

`A= [x1 , y1;
    x2 , y2;
    x3 , y3]`

and i want to remove selected points (rows) that their y value is above some deviation from the average.

How can i do this ?

Thank you,
Ron

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is what you seem to need:

```
A(abs(A(:,2)-mean(A(:,2)))>treshold,:) = []
```

If you want you can let the treshold be something like

```
1.234*std(A(:,2))
```

Comment: @Divakar I don't understand your point. The standard deviation is independant of (shifts in) the mean `std(1:5)` is the same as `std(6:10)`. Basing the treshold on the standard deviation multiplied by a constant seems to be a very natural solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
A(A(:,2) > mean(A(:,2) + ScaleFactor*std(A(:,2)),:) = [];
```

ScaleFactor will depend on what your criteria is..

Comment: This doesn't work, because the OP says "deviation", i.e. above or below

Comment: How does `std` comes in?

Comment: It still doesn't work. You are only considering the "above" case, not the "below" case

Comment: Also, you want to delete the rows, not the columns. It must be `A(whatevs, :) = [];`.

Comment: @Divakar std comes in because of deviation part. by using std, i can calculate the standard deviation away from the mean..

Comment: @lakesh One thing is deviation (difference) and a different thing is _standard_ deviation (`std`)

Comment: @LuisMendo sorry about that part, was thinking abt the standard deviation part... then the second term becomes addition/subtraction..